# Register libusb for pkg-confg

Tags: pkg-config, libusb-1.0

I want to compile the [lm4flash](https://github.com/utzig/lm4tools/tree/master/lm4flash) tool for my Stellaris Launchpad, but when I run the make command, it returns an error, because libusb 1.0 isn't installed.

How can I register the libusb library on pkg-config (I only have the bare dev-library you can download from their website)?

I tried to search for a solution with Google, but I couldn't find a answer.

I'm using Windows 7 and already installed pkg-config, a cross compiler (for ARM) and MinGW.

Thank you for help,
Turakar

Comment: Did you try to add a directory with *.pc files to $PKG_CONFIG_PATH ?

Comment: I'm using a parallel boot system now (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04) and used apt-get to install all necessary libraries (inc libusb), so the problem is solved in some manner. But thank you anyway, as my problem seems to be a general problem, so I might be able to use your suggestion on another/new system.